# Hello World en C Linux mint

Tags: linux, codeblocks

quisiera que me ayudarán con un error que tengo: estoy empezando a aprender el lenguaje C y para ello instale code blocks en Linux mint, al parecer ya estaba instalado el compilador gcc por ende no inatale ningún otro. El problema es que cuando compilo el clásico hello wolrd  me aparece el siguiente error: g++ no such file or directory

Comment: Hola Camilo, podrías añadir el código de tu programa . para tener un mejor contexto del error. Gracias.

Comment: Es el código por defecto que crea code blocks es algo así como: <include studio.sh><iostream> Main(){ printf("hello wolrd \n")return0} o algo así perdón es que estoy desde mi teléfono

Comment: no such file or directory = No encuentra el fichero. , por consiguiente ejecuta el gcc en el directorio en el que se encuentra el fichero a compilar.

Comment: Instala g++: sudo apt-get install g++

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.

Comment: Hola, también utilizo Linux Mint con CodeBlocks te adjunto una captura del Compiler Settings: https://i.imgur.com/4ZrJnMA.png

Answer (score 0):

Si, tenes un hello.c, tenes que compilarlo con la instruccion:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

y el paquete gcc instalado.

Comment: Si  es que  gcc ya está instalado y he compilado mediante code blocks y me sale el error el directorio es el que crea el programa por defecto

Comment: Ok, entiendo, lo que supongo entonces es que no debes tener configurado correctamente el proyecto en el Code::Blocks.
Por favor, incluye un printscreen o data de como estas definiendo.

Comment: Como estoy definiendo???  Lo siento No se a que te refieres

Comment: @CamiloMartinez, tenes en Codeblock una sección donde definir el  proyecto [ver] (http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
no such file or directory
```

Simplemente no existe un fichero o directorio con ese nombre , los pasos a hacer son :

```
cd /al/directorio/
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

Lo que pasa es que no estás situado en el directorio donde se sitúa el fichero.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, tienes instalado el gcc.

¿ y el g++ ? Son 2 cosas distintas.

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends install g++
```